# convert text field to double java

Tags: java, textfield

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to getting input from user by `TextField` and convert it to `double`. I saw here that I should use `parseDouble` but it's not working and I don't know where is my mistake. here's the relevnt part of my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
if(e.getSource()==cur1)
        {
            //frame.setVisible(true);
            cur1.setVisible(false);
            cur2.setVisible(false);
            cur3.setVisible(false);
            label.setText("Enter USD amount");
            edit.setVisible(true);
            //double d = Double.parseDouble(edit.getText()); 
            edit.setLayout(null);
            button1.setVisible(true);
            button1.setText("next");
            button1.setSize(90,20);
            button1.setBounds(250, 250, 100, 20);
            s=edit.getText();
            button1.addActionListener(this);    
        }
        
        
        if(e.getSource()==button1)
        {
            val=Double.parseDouble(s);
            val=val*3.55;
            label.setVisible(true);
            label.setText("The value is"+val);
            }
        }
```

*I defined `double val` and `String s` earlier.

the red sentences:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:651)
    at currency.currency2.actionPerformed(currency2.java:117)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

thank you!

Comment: What does [not working](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/77-doesntwork) mean? Also, [Avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)

Comment: not working means that wnen I press button1 I get screen with a lot of red sentences

Comment: the layouts are ok

Comment: The 'red sentences' explain what's wrong. Just read them and fix the problem. If you do not understand what they say, edit this question and include them. Until then, vote-to-close, insufficient detail.

Comment: I added the sentences now

Comment: Might also be a good idea to utilize a [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) for your JTextField so that only numerical values can be entered.

Answer (score 1):

Since their is an exception while the String is not equal to a number, for example "" or "hi" you can just use

```
try {
    val=Double.parseDouble(s);
    val=val*3.55;
    label.setVisible(true);
    label.setText("The value is"+val);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
```

Button1 now does nothing if its pressed and s is not a number.
You can also write:

```
catch(Exception e) {
label.setText("The Input needs to be a number");
    }
```

The label should now change its text to "The Input needs to be a number" if you press the button and s is not equal to a number.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String` means that you try to parse an empty string. You have to check the string and if it is blank, then retrieve `.0` or `null` or `Double.NaN` - whatever you like, but do not call `Double.parseDouble()` on blank string.

```java
TextField textField = new TextField("123.456");
String s = textField.getText();
double value = s == null || s.isBlank() ? Double.NaN : Double.parseDouble(s.trim()); // 123.456
```